# How can I connect myremotesql to Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I tried to connect RemoteMySql as a host with PyMySql, it neither shows an error nor does it work.

The code is below:

```py
db = pymysql.connect(
    host="remotemysql.com",user="USER",
    password="PASSWORD",db="DBNAME")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (ID, name, password,email) VALUES (93454623021,'Jeff','12345','mail@gmail.com');")
db.close()
```

I also changed the host to *localhost*, but it showed this error:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)")
```

It does work when I test it in phpMyAdmin but it does not work when I do it in any other compiler, it does not insert the data to the table so, what actually am I missing?

Comment: Is remote connection to the mysql server's port allowed on the remote server? Is the remote mysql configured to accept remote connections?

Comment: @Shadow i do not know, how can i check?

Comment: If the remote mysql is on a managed hosting, then you need to ask your hosting provider. If you manage the server, then port routing is eithet operating system specific or if you use cpanel or something similar, then dependent on this software. For mysql you can find it here on SO.

Comment: Your use of `\*\*` is really not warranted. Just write normally.

Comment: Why are you inserting `ID` into a table?

Comment: Tip: Check that your connection succeeded before using it.

Comment: shouldn't `b` be `db` ie `db= pymysql.connect(
    host="remotemysql.com",user="USER",
    password="PASSWORD",db="DBNAME")`

Comment: @3kstc It's assumed the `d` got lost in the copy-paste excursion.

Comment: @tadman i am inserting it as an index to link 2 tables, i know there is a better way, but i like this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This source code is correct.

At issue is: "does the client have TCP connectivity to the server?".

It's easy to check.
Use any one of these commands.

```
$ ncat remotemysql.com 3306
L
8.0.13-4???3E>Z/l8Q?????hC+!h&CsNmysql_native_password
^C
$
$ telnet remotemysql.com 3306
Trying 37.59.55.185...
Connected to remotemysql.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
L
8.0.13-4}??/}>lkfJ??zf+*P
                         }XNN^mysql_native_password
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.
$
$ time curl http://remotemysql.com:3306
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

real    0m0.500s
```

If your local firewall is blocking such
packets, and you can change the firewall
config, arrange for it to pass outbound
TCP port 3306 connections, to support
the mysql DB protocol.

If you are blocked and cannot change
the config, then seek another connectivity
solution.